# Upgrading Ubuntu versions, keep files but remove programs

Tags: upgrade, files, 16.04

I'm trying to upgrade from version 15.10 to 16.04 LTS of Ubuntu. I don't have an external hard drive to back up my files to (it's a gaming laptop), so I would have to place my files somewhere else on the hard drive or folder. Either way, is there a way to upgrade Ubuntu *fresh* while keeping my files (like removing all of my installed applications but keep my photos)? Maybe, for example, repartitioning the hard drive?

Comment: is your `/home` directory a separate partition or do you have the typical `/ and swap` partition setup?

Comment: It is `/ and swap`.

Comment: well ... the home directory is what you need to keep but since its located in the /  partition that wont be possible. USB  drives are cheep now a days ...the only safe way is to go to  your  files  explorer and make sure it shows hidden files then make a copy of your home directory onto a flash drive. then you could  at least save your files and do a clean install.  other than that .. do a  search on google and I believe there are some tutorials on how to get back to a factory state by removing a bunch of stuff then  installing other stuff .. but ... it keeps the home directory intact

Comment: i believe it involves removing the desktop environment which will uninstall most other programs due to dependencies then reinstalling the desktop environment but this explanation is very general. its always best to have a backup of your personal files anyway because .. you never know when a drive can fail .. I had it happen to me and lost about 7 years of my life because I was  too lazy to backup ... now .. lol I have 2 copies of all my files .. well 2 backups and the originals :D lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a little tricky since you don't have an external drive to copy your files to, but it shouldn't end up terribly. **I still think you should get at least a >32GB flash drive as a temporary backup in case things go badly.**

I think the best plan is to downsize your current Ubuntu partition as much as possible (you can resize it further during the installation, but it's good to at least start) and then use that partition as your data partition. The data partition will be integrated, so there will be no need for manual copying.

Here's the procedure:

## Preparation

1. Create your installation media. I recommend a USB stick instead of a DVD. There are countless tutorials on how to burn to a USB, so I won't provide instructions here.
2. Create a backup of `/home` somehow. You don't have to do this, but I strongly recommend it. `/home` will be big, so you'll need a big flash drive.

## Setup

1. Install Gparted so you can resize your partitions:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gparted
   ```
2. Open Gparted and find the partition of your Ubuntu installation. It shouldn't be hard to find; it should be the big `ext4` partition, provided you don't have a multi-boot situation.
3. Right click this partition and choose the `Resize/Move` option. Resize the partition from the right until there's about 10GB free space
4. Hit <kbd>OK</kbd> and then the `Apply` button (the green checkmark).

## More setup

1. Boot into your Ubuntu installation: choose the `Try Ubuntu` option, as there is some more setup needed.
2. Search for and open Gparted. It's already installed in the Live Environment.
3. Create a new `ext4` partition in the free space you created before and apply the operation.
4. Once the operation is finished, open the file browser and click the partition in the sidebar to mount it.
5. Right click the partition and choose the `Properties` option. Record the UUID or name given there.
6. Now, open a terminal. Run:

   ```
   sudo cp -pr /home /media/ubuntu/THENAMEYOUCOPIEDEARLIER/
   ```

   - That should copy everything in your Home directory to the other partition.
7. Once the copying is finished, go back to Gparted.
8. Now, format the **Ubuntu installation partition** as `ext4`. ***Make sure it isn't the data partition.***
9. Now, downsize that installation partition even more. Make it 40-60GB, depending on how big your hard drive is.

   - You want your data partition to be bigger than the installation partition.
10. Unmount the data partition and move it to the left to fill the newly-created free space.
11. Resize it to fill the free space.
12. Apply the operation. It might take a while, so give yourself some time.
13. Remount the data partition and find your user folder there. Rename it to something else. `username1` is fine if you want.

## Installation

1. Open the installer and go through the steps until you reach the installation location options.
2. Choose `Something Else...` and continue.
3. Right click the installation partition and go into the properties.
4. Choose to use it as an `ext4` partition and mount it at `/`.
5. Do the same for the data partition, but mount it as `/home`.

   - Make sure that the `Format` option **is not** checked for this partition. The other one doesn't matter.
6. Proceed with the installation.

## Post-Install

1. When the installation finishes, don't restart. Instead, open the file browser and mount the data partition.
2. Run:

   ```
   sudo cp -pr /media/ubuntu/THATUUIDYOUCOPIEDEARLIER/THEUSERFOLDERYOURENAMED/ /media/ubuntu/THEUUIDAGAIN/THEUSERFOLDERTHEINSTALLATIONCREATED/
   ```

   - That will copy the files from your old user folder into the new one.
3. Now you can reboot into Ubuntu.

## Conclusion (I guess?)

Hopefully, this will give you a full data transfer, but also a fresh reinstall.

To save space, I recommend deleting the old user folder.

Again: ***Please be careful. I REALLY recommend that you at least copy what you need to a flash drive.*** Ubuntu can always go crazy, as with any OS.

If you want to be cautious and need any more explanation for something, please ask. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: About copying to a flash drive: I've heard that resizing partitions can sometimes corrupt data. To what extent is this true?

Comment: It's completely true; the risk just isn't very high. That's one of my reasons for recommending a backup.